# When I press a UIButton the UITextField text come in to NSArray and display in UITableView

Tags: ios

```
-(IBAction)clicked:(id)sender 
{ 
    NSString *productName=[NSStringstringWithFormat:@"%@",textfield.text];
    [cartArray addObject:productName];
    NSLog(@"Cart Array==%@",cartArray);
 }

-(void)viewDidLoad:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidLoad:animated];
    cartArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
```

Comment: Edit your question with the problem you've?

Comment: You need to go and find a basic table view tutorial . Go search the web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume If u have tableView and its datasource array is cartArray

```
-(IBAction)clicked:(id)sender 
{ 
  if(textfield.text.length>0)  
  {
   [cartArray addObject:textfield.text]; 
  }
  NSLog(@"Cart Array==%@",cartArray);

  //Now Reload tableView
  [yourTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: thank u so much prince for answering ...

Comment: you have solved my problem for displaying in uitable view..

Comment: but when i reopening my app i couldnt find the array ,,,what to do...i want that once i enter in textfield and it display on array..it should be there all the time..

Answer (score 0):

Ya prince is correct as he said if you want that your textfield value should in tableview when you press any particular button then you need to reload your tableview.

But first you need to check the length of textfield text. If it is nil and if you pass that array value to datasource method then it will give you null pointer exception.

Like in this method-

```
  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  {
    return  [array count];
   }
```

then array should contain some value then only tableview will come. otherwise no tableview will come. or may be it gives you error like "object cannot be nil".